# Redundant regex in SELECT and WHERE

Tags: regex, postgresql, greenplum

Is there a better way to do this? Seems silly to have the same regex twice, but I want to indicate which phrase triggered the message content that was selected. Greenplum 4.2.2.4 (like PostgreSQL 8.2) on server.

```
SELECT
to_timestamp(extrainfo.startdate/1000)
,messages.timestamp
,users.username
,substring(messages.content from E'(?i)phrase number one|phrase\.two|another phrase|this list keeps going|lots\.of\*keyword phrases|more will be added in the future')
,messages.content

FROM users
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.senderid = users.id
LEFT JOIN extrainfo ON extrainfo.username = users.username

WHERE extrainfo.type1 = 't'
AND messages.content ~* E'phrase number one|phrase\.two|another phrase|this list keeps going|lots\.of\*keyword phrases|more will be added in the future'
AND (extrainfo.type2 = 'f' OR extrainfo.type2 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Is it really PostgreSQL 8.2 (ancient version) or are you using Greenplum or Redshift?

Comment: SELECT version() returns: PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.2.4 build 1 Community Edition) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Oct 17 2012 11:52:28

Comment: If you are using Greenplum, please don't say it's PostgreSQL. It isn't. It's Greenplum Database. It has very different features and capabilities to real PostgreSQL. I fixed your question for you.

Comment: That is good to know. I am not a DBA, so was not aware. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using basic join:

```
SELECT
   to_timestamp(extrainfo.startdate/1000)
   ,messages.timestamp
   ,users.username
   ,substring(messages.content from rgxp.rgxp )
   ,messages.content
FROM users
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.senderid = users.id
join ( 
  select E'(?i)phrase number one|phrase\.two|another phrase|this list keeps going|lots\.of\*keyword phrases|more will be added in the future'::text
      as rgxp
) rgxp
on messages.content ~* rgxp.rgxp
LEFT JOIN extrainfo ON extrainfo.username = users.username
WHERE extrainfo.type1 = 't'
AND (extrainfo.type2 = 'f' OR extrainfo.type2 IS NULL)
```

This is a demo (for one table only): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/4a00d/2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems to be working to some degree, but does not fully populate the substring column (most of the entries are returned as null).

Comment: Never mind, I had a typo in the code. Corrected and working now! Thank you so much :)